# Java NIO 2 DirectoryStream list changes when file is changed

Tags: java, nio2

I have noticed a weird behavior when listing files in a directory. My situation is i have a list of txt files which i save in database and corresponding to those data files there are xml file that contains some tags for each txt which are associated as their meta-properties in db.

When i list files in from directory and read xml file some how the stream is changing and listing the file again which has already been added to db. Filenames are id in my db and are unique,re-listing them violates the primary key constraint.

i wanted to know why does the listing gets disturbed?

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(folderReader,filter){
    for (Path file : directoryStream) {
         // Read XML
         // add txt file to database
         // attach meta props to that file
    }
    }catch(IOException ex){}
```

Now for some file it runs fine but then some how the files that had already been listed are coming back again. Like 1.txt was processed and saved in db but in the loop later on it is listed again.

Comment: I am using dom4j for reading xml.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by stream is changing? Can you post your code in pastebin or somewhere.

Comment: i have also found this line in documentation. 

"The iterator is weakly consistent. It is thread safe but does not freeze the directory while iterating, so it may (or may not) reflect updates to the directory that occur after the DirectoryStream is created."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115698/java-nio-2-directorystream-list-changes-when-file-is-changed#comment37204051_24115698) seems to describe exactly what happens here.

I guess the `DirectoryStream` adds (or adds not) newly saved files without checking for their prior listing.

In this case, it's probably a good idea to add the entries from the `DirectoryStream` to another `Iterable` or even `Set` (e.g. `HashSet`) before handling them and check if they are were in the `Set` before ([`Set#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) return's boolean for that reason).

Comment: Yes that is what i did exactly. Using Hashset solved the issue for me.